# Crud for existing model in YII

Tags: yii, crud, gii

I am trying to create CRUD for my model classed generated automatically by GII.

Classes are stored like **models/entity/Article.php**. When i try to Gii generator put as class name models.entity.SomeClass or entity.SomeClass it doesn`t work.

The gii stops with exception **Alias "entity.Article" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file.**

How can I run CRUD script properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the alias in your *config/main.php* file (do this before the `return array`):

```php
Yii::setPathOfAlias('entity',dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'../models/entity');

// rest of config
return array(
    // ...
);
```

Then use `entity.Article` in gii.